# VB.NET DownloadFileAsync fires completion event but doesn't download

Tags: vb.net, file, asynchronous, download, progress

I'm trying to download a .zip file to make an auto-updater for my game. It needs to show progress. I followed an online tutorial and got this chunk of code for the actual downloader:

```
    Dim SaveDirectory As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyGame\"
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient
    AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_ProgressChanged
    AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client_DownloadCompleted
    client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https://example.com/game/download/latest.zip"), SaveDirectory)
```

My problem now, is that when I run the Windows Form application, the DownloadFileCompleted event is fired, yet the file **is not** downloading for some reason.

It's about a 34 MB .zip file. Any help appreciated, and many thanks.

Comment: Found a mistake, but it still didn't fix my problem. For the second DownloadFileAsync parameter, I put a folder, not a file name. I fixed that, but again, my problem is not fixed and remains an annoyance. :C

Comment: r u sure the download link do not need any kind of authorization?

Comment: I am sure. I've also tried both http:// and https:// - no difference.

Comment: please check the `e.Error` property  for DownloadFileCompleted. make sure it is null! if its not null, check what kind of exception error it holds!

Comment: System.Net.WebException {"An exception occurred during a WebClient request."}  HResult  -2146233079

Comment: Oh, it has no access to the save path. Derr.

Comment: there you go, problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `DownloadFileCompleted` is fired, do check a few thing.

For a successful download

- `e.Cancelled` must be false.
- `e.Error` should be null

if `e.Error` is not `null`, then it hold the Exception object, that describes the detail of what went wrong with the `Async Operation`