# C# Hangs when downloading a file

Tags: c#, download

Download and hang 20% 40% -> `client_DownloadFileCompleted` that is, as if it completed but the file is not downloaded completely

**How to fix ?**

```
MessageBox.Show("Пожалуйста ожидайте начинаем процесс скачивание клиента", "тест",
 MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Proxy = null;
client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://***/test.7z"), @"test.7z");


    void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Клиент успешно скачался,Ожидайте идет процесс распаковки.", "тест", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a duplicate of [VB.NET DownloadFileAsync fires completion event but doesn't download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458463/vb-net-downloadfileasync-fires-completion-event-but-doesnt-download) where the programmer is not checking the AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled and .Error properties.

You are assuming that the event fires becasue the download is successful, but actually it fires when the download is completed; but it may be reporting a download failure. Check the event args passed into the event to see if its been successful.